# The text format within <pre></pre> is gone, what's wrong?

Tags: html, css, layout, newline

I input some text in `<textarea></textarea>`, I enter some line breaks, spaces,etc. purposely. However, after the text is submitted and rendered within `<pre></pre>`, the newline, whitespaces are gone, they are replaced by something like `\r\n\r\n`, what's wrong? How can I keep the original format?

```
 <textarea name="detail" id="detail" rows="7" cols="60" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $detail ?></textarea>
```

I render the text in HTML.

This is the output:

> The urban agglomeration of the
>   Hangzhou metropolitan area (杭州市区) has
>   a resident population of 3.9319
>   million as of 2003, of which 2.6367
>   million ...\\\\r\\\\nHangzhou
>   is located in northern Zhejiang
>   province, eastern China, at the
>   southern end of the Grand Canal of
>   China, on the plain of the mid
>   ...\\\\r\\\\nIn late summer
>   (August to September), Hangzhou, along
>   with other cities in Zhejiang
>   province, suffer typhoon storms, but
>   typhoons seldom strike it directly.
>   Generally. Edited\r\n\r\nAnother line.

The data-type is varchar(MySQL), does it have anything with the problem?

Comment: rendering tool? What do you mean?

Comment: I am using HTML,PHP, and MySQL.

Comment: By rendering tool he probably means what browser, as browsers will ignore \r and \n formatting, acknowledging only html formatting tags and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your output through the [nl2br](https://www.php.net/nl2br) function first:

```
<pre><?php echo nl2br($content) ?></pre>
```

Make sure you escape the data to protect against nasty input at some point too - either before you stick it in the database using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or when you print it to the screen using [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: The data doesn't have new lines in it, it has something which resolves to the literal sequence `\r\n`, presumably there is some double escaping going on down the line.

Comment: The literal sequence \r\n _is_ a newline sequence - example #2 on http://ca2.php.net/nl2br describes *exactly* this situation, whereby \r\n literals are replaced with <br/> tags.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

[Allow HTML in TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897452/allow-html-in-textarea)

**asp.net**

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering these into a web app? One you wrote? What's probably happening is they're being recognised as new lines.  On Windows platforms, a paragraph/newline is done with a \r (carriage return) and \n (new line).  If you're then redisplaying them on a new page or site, you'll need to sub back in some html, or else in the original submit, replace \r\n with 
`<pre>(whitespaceofyourchoice)<\pre>`.

\r and \n are ASCII characters and not part of HTML formatting.  As such, web browsers will choose to ignore them.